# Use an output device as a recording source under Vista/Win7 new sound API?

Tags: winapi, audio, audio-recording

As I understand it, Vista introduced a completely rearchitectured sound input/output system to the OS. In particular, before Vista there was a single system-wide sound mixer, to which output devices could be connected. For recording, it was possible to retrieve data directly from a recording device or from this mixer.

In Vista and later, as I understand it, there is no longer a system-wide mixer. It is possible, in theory, to route some sounds to one output device and other sounds to a different output device,<sup>1</sup> and this requires separate mixers for each output device.

Now, I have a simple recording application that I would like to update to take advantage of this new API. In particular, I was hoping it would be possible to let the user select one of the *output* devices as an audio data source. My reasoning is that the OS probably mixes all the inputs into each sound device anyway, and hopefully provides a way to tap into the mixed data.

Is it possible to select an output device as an input into my recording application, and if so, how?

<sup>1</sup><sub>Although I am yet to find any UI that actually lets one do this.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[Loopback Recording](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)